# Gulp plugins for build version HTML pages

Tags: javascript, build, gulp, frontend

Good time of day!
The projects collect Gulp, I came to the conclusion that in order to support these projects, it is necessary to know the version of the collected pages hosted on a remote server and the version of the source that would know that a server is always available a new version of the assembly. Do to this problem some sort of plug-Gulp, which, when you build the project, such as a key --production stamped version of the bottom of the page, or in a special unit in the comments?

Comment: please be more specific, perhaps with an example of what you're trying to achieve and what you have tried so far. This question is extremely vague.

Answer (score -1):

A popular plugin that can do this is [`gulp-bump`](https://github.com/stevelacy/gulp-bump), and there's the newcomer [`gulp-append`](https://github.com/SkeLLLa/gulp-version-append).

But also check out the answers at [gulp: Automatically add version number to request for preventing browser cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573508/gulp-automatically-add-version-number-to-request-for-preventing-browser-cache)