# Versioning with gulp

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, gulp

I'm little confused in versioning process and I'm not sure if it's possible.

I have gulp task that bundles and minifies the js files but each time I have to change the folder path in .dest and hit gulp command to generate file (Like 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 2.0.0 etc). I'mm using semantic versioning approach.

Now I want files like:

```
https://{url}/1.0.0/file.js
https://{url}/1.0.1/file.js
https://{url}/1.1.0/file.js
https://{url}/2.0.0/file.js
.....
```

So is there any way to automate this process? Like we have in npmjs or what is the best way for versioning?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573508/gulp-automatically-add-version-number-to-request-for-preventing-browser-cache

Comment: That question is for cache busting, which is (at least arguably, depending on OP) different.