# Change name of css file in html by gulp

Tags: gulp

I get a trouble. I using Gulp. Here is my html file in folder /app. I want to custom name css file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app_v2.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app_v2.css?v=yyyy-mm-dd">
```

when I build from /app to /dest.
Here is my config build

```
gulp.task('build:dev', ['clean', 'config:development'], function() {
    gulp.start('create');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head ng-controller="titleCtrl">
<base href="/">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app_v2.css">
</head>
<body itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
    <global-nav ng-controller="menuCtrl"></global-nav>
    <div ng-view class="page-content"></div>
    <footer ng-controller="footerCtrl"></footer>
  <script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've never used gulp before so I'm very confused. With any advice please let me know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `css` remove the tag from your question

Comment: Your intention seems to be cache busting. Check out https://github.com/jhuesos/gulp-cachebust

Comment: You can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573508/gulp-automatically-add-version-number-to-request-for-preventing-browser-cache

Comment: @Ved, thanks so much